# AngularJS file download after $http.post success

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a angular service where a request is sent to the backend to generate the file, the front end and backend both shares a request ID to communicate for the task later.

After the file generation is done, the backend sends back a success flag with a download URL of the "form api/filegenerator/requestID:/download", where when called, the file generated will be passed back.

How would I do it so that when $http.post(...).success() is called, I can just directly call that download link without user interaction? (no download button or anything in the HTML)

Answer (score 3):

You can use $window.location

```
$http.post(...)
  .then(function(url) {
    $window.location = url;
  }
```

or simulate user click to fake button

```
function downloadURIWithFakeClick(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}

downloadURIWithFakeClick(url);
```

You can see both solutions in this example http://plnkr.co/edit/WbNvAth8tP1yR3sRmkAw?p=preview